# How do I know if a user is following me on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

I know Instagram shows only the last 200 followers on the Followers list, even if you have more than that. So, is there any other way (maybe through another service?) I can tell if a certain user is following me, if that user is not in the list of 200 recent followers?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply send a DM to them and ask but a more efficient way is to get the app called followers+ I'm guessing you would be following them so just look under users not following back if there under there they are not following you but if you are not following them you can click users I'm not following back and if they are under that list they are following you if they are not on that list they are not following you.

Comment: You need to clarify this a bit as it's just one run-on sentence.